# JQuery is not detecting my DOM Object when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Having a bit of trouble figuring out what is going wrong here and wondered if anyone might be able to help me out. I'm using `JQuery` throughout my site but for some reason on this particular page it does not seem to be working.

This code here:

```
$("#keyword").autocomplete({                        
    source:'../../pages/ajax/autocomplete/autocomplete_tags.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    minLength:1
});

//When you hit the search button load the new tags
$("#srchBtn").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var tag_name = $('#keyword').val();
    $(".dashboardtable").load('../../pages/ajax/autocomplete/search_tags.php', {tag_name: tag_name },function(response, status, xhr){
            $(".dashboardtable").html(response);
            $("#keyword").val("");
            $("#keyword").attr("placeholder", "Search Tags...");
    });
});
```

What should happen is when the user begins typing it begins pulling suggestions out of the database and when they click the search button it loads the results into a div using `AJAX`. I noticed it wasn't working and I decided I'd try a simple test:

```
$('#srchBtn').click(function(){
    console.log('hit');
})
```

But nothing appeared in the console. I then tried

`console.log($('#srchBtn'));` and It does seem to be getting a reference to my dom object, it just isn't firing the click event for some reason.

I've got the following `scripts` at the top of the page:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
 <script src="../scripts/auto-complete/tag_list_search.js"></script>
```

and I am getting no errors in my console. So what could possibly be the problem? Any help is much appreciated. Also this is my `HTML`:

```
<input type="text" id="keyword" placeholder="Search Tags..." size="33"/>
<input type="button" class="" id="srchBtn" value="Search"/>
```

Comment: `console.log('#srchBtn');` simply logs the string `#srchBtn`. It doesn't get a reference to an element. Is *all* your code included at the top of the page?

Comment: That was a typo on my part, i've updated the question. Yes it is

Answer (score 0):

```
Please wrap the code in jquery ready function...(in case this is not done)

$(function(){ // jquery ready function
$("#keyword").autocomplete({                        
    source:'../../pages/ajax/autocomplete/autocomplete_tags.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    minLength:1
});

//When you hit the search button load the new tags
$("#srchBtn").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var tag_name = $('#keyword').val();
    $(".dashboardtable").load('../../pages/ajax/autocomplete/search_tags.php', {tag_name: tag_name },function(response, status, xhr){
            $(".dashboardtable").html(response);
            $("#keyword").val("");
            $("#keyword").attr("placeholder", "Search Tags...");
    });
});
});
```